# I can't detach from my screen (Linux-ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I have a major problem.
 I screened a program, but i cannot detach from it.

Ctrl+a Ctrl+d just don't do anything. 
 They will be displayed as ^A or ^D , which is really annoying.

I cannot Ctrl+a and d , they just don't to anything.

Can someone help me, i want to turn of my computer :D, so i can leave from the computer... I NEED SLEEP.

Comment: I thought turning off your machine would detach it by default ?

Comment: I have the same problem! Can you help me in it?

Answer (score 3):

Login to the screen host and run `screen -D` to detach your screen session.